# Unable to import Python package universally

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following directory structure:

```
workspace/
  __init__.py
  ys_manage/
    __init__.py
    manage.py
  ys_utils/
    __init__.py
    project_dicts.py
```

Now, suppose I need access to `project_dicts.py` in `manage.py`.  Also, my `$PATH` includes `/home/rico/workspace/ys_manage`.

I need to be able to run `manage.py` from any directory on my machine and still be able to access `project_dicts.py`.

My `$PYTHONPATH` only has `/home/rico/workspace`.

If I include the following in `manage.py` I can run the file from `~/workspace/ys_manage` but not anywhere else.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
from ys_utils import project_dicts
```

It appears that the `'..'` gives a relative path to where the directory where the file is run, not where the file is located.  Is this correct?

I wanted to try and use `ys_manage/__init__.py` to import `project_dicts.py` so that it would be available in `manage.py` universally.  Is this a good idea?

I've never used `__init__.py` for anything other than a "package creator".  That is, I've never used it for initialization purposes.  Perhaps I'm doing it wrong.

Contents of `ys_manage/__init__.py`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
from ys_utils import project_dicts
```

Should I include something in `manage.py` to look for this import?

When I try and run `manage.py` I get the following error:

```
NameError: global name 'project_dicts' is not defined
```

As a secondary question, do I need to have `workspace/__init__.py`?  I'd really rather not have it because `ys_manage` and `ys_utils` (and about a dozen other packages) are all under revision control and used by several other developers...`workspace` is not.

Comment: check out virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/

Comment: My project has many contributors.  Is this something I can setup for everyone who uses my project?  Or does each person need to install and configure this for themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead of `sys.path.append('..')`:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
```

(you'll need to import both sys and os).

Answer (score 3):

Generally, I've found trying to use relative paths for imports dangerous and very error prone.  I'd suggest just putting workspace on your PYTHONPATH (or adding it programatically in `__init__.py`) and importing everything relative to that static location. It will make your code more easily readable too, as you'll be able to track down where imports are coming from much more quickly and clearly.

Comment: Which `__init__.py` are you referring to?  The one in `workspace` or `ys_manage`?

Comment: @Rico Depends on how you run this whole thing.  If you are running manage.py directly from the command line, you could actually put the PYTHONPATH modification in that file itself to get the results you want.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure which was the most Pythonic method.  Thank you.